# Is there an algorithm/method for actually drawing Van Kampen diagrams?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, group-presentation

In theory, given a presentation for a group, I understand what a Van Kampen diagram should look like, but I struggle when it comes to the practicalities of drawing it.

> Is there an algorithm/method for actually drawing them?

For example, if I wanted to draw the Van Kampen diagram for $ \left< a , b | a^8, a^2 b a^{-1} b^{-2} \right>$, how would I go about drawing it?

Comment: Usually a van Kampen diagram refers to a (planar) diagram realizing a given word over the generating set as a representative of the identity in the given group.  So, you need to chose a word to get started.  As to a method, this is typically not possible in an efficient way.  If you know that a word represents the identity in your group, then you can start to enumerate the normal closure of the relators and then freely reduce and at some point your word will appear.  Your group is rather nice however.  If you omit the relator $a^8$, then that group is a 1-relator group satisfying C(6).

Comment: I know what a Van Kampen diagram is, but given a presentation (which includes generators and relations) I have no idea how to go about drawing one. Just wondered whether or not there was an algorithm for it or not.

Comment: Yes, the process described in my comment above is an algorithm which takes as input a word in the generators that you know to represent the identity in the given finitely presented group and returns a word in in the generators that is a product of conjugates of relators and which is freely equal to the word you started with.  (This algorithm is not efficient!  And to be of use in practice, you'd need to have some other way of knowing that a word represents the identity in your group.) Given a product of conjugates of relators you can simply draw a planar diagram.  You can then reduce

Comment: this diagram.  The classic text by Lyndon and Schupp illustrates how to obtain a reduced diagram (and proves these always exist).  The text Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups by Olshanskiy gives a more careful treatment of these ideas.

Comment: It's the drawing of the diagram that I'm having trouble with, not identifying the relations that are part of it though. I don't think the drawing of it is simple and that's what my question is about - not finding the necessary relations for the diagram

Comment: Draw a wedge of lollipops: one disk for each relator and a bunch of stems for the conjugating elements.

Comment: Any algorithm for drawing a diagram with boundary a given word must be somehow "bad". This is because if we could somehow find a bound the algorithm we would be able to decide if a given word was trivial or not (run the algorithm; if the algorithm terminates then the word is trivial, while if the algorithm exceeds the bound then it is non-trivial).

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a tool for visualizing van Kampen diagrams. About how it works and what input format you can see on
[project GitHub page](https://github.com/Glebanister/van_kampen_diagramm).
Here is [example of work result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blKGt.jpg)